# Why does Greek have 'aorgesia' and 'aorist' rather than 'anorgesia' and 'anorist'?

Tags: etymology, greek

The Ancient Greek words [ἀοργησία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29orghsi%2Fa&la=greek&can=a%29orghsi%2Fa0) *aorgesia* "a defect in the passion of anger" and [ἀόριστος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29o%2Fristos&la=greek&can=a%29o%2Fristos0) *aoristos* "without boundaries" both start with the "alpha privatum," the negative prefix cognate to English *un-* and Latin *-in/-im/-ir/-il*. However, every source that I have looked up has said that this prefix is realized as ἀν- *an*- when it comes before a vowel (including one that was historically preceded by a rough breathing /h/).
What is the explanation for these exceptions, and do any others exist?

EDIT: I kind of found the answer, so I guess I will post it in case anyone else has this problem later on. I may have follow-up questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of these roots originally had an initial w-. horos “boundary” is from older worwos, as attested by Mycenaean wo-wo, and dialect forms like ορϝος. In the case of orgē “anger” we do not happen to have any attested Greek dialect forms with w-, but IE *uerg- is supported by zero-grade forms like Sanskrit ūrj- “strength”.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Perseus online dictionary of Ancient Greek](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=a)1):

> Before a vowel [the prefix ἀ-] usu. appears as ἀν- (exc. where ϝ or
>   spiritus asper has been lost, as ἄ-οινος, ἄ-υπνος, when it sts.
>   coalesces with the following vowel, as ἀργός = ἀ-ϝεργός)

So this points towards one possible reason for the lack of nu in the words I asked about.

Looking up their etymology yielded the following information:

**aorgesia:** related to the word [ὀργή](http://biblehub.com/greek/3709.htm) *orgē* "wrath".

According to the sources listed at the "Biblehub" site, the word orgē may come:

- according to Strong's Exhaustive Concordance, from oregomai, the middle voice of [ὀρέγω](http://biblehub.com/greek/3713.htm) *oregō* "to reach out," which [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CE%AD%CE%B3%CF%89) says derives from PIE [*h₃reǵ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%83re%C7%B5-). This is a problem, since with this etymology there is never a digamma /w/ or spiritus asper /h/.
- according to HELPS Word-studies, from the verb "orgáō" or "oragō" [sic] "to teem, to swell" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%AC%CF%89) says it is ὀργάω *orgáō* and that it is derived from the noun, rather than the other way around).
- according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%AE), from PIE *werǵ-/*worǵ-. This suggests a form with digamma once existed, though I have not been able to find that.

This suggests that the etymology attributed to Strong's is incorrect.

**aorist**: there was historically a spiritus asper /h/ as shown by the related word [ὅρος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%85%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) *horos* "boundary."

I was confused before researching this because later on, at least in English words of Greek origin, the *an-* form started to be used before roots with historical spiritus asper, but I don't know when this occurred. (This can be seen in English words like *anemia, anhydrous, anhedonia* etc. I've been trying to find equivalent words in Greek though.)

Comment: It would be better to look these up in a proper etymological dictionary (most recently Beekes).

Comment: @fdb: yes, unfortunately I don't have one. When I wrote the question, I didn't realize that the answer would have to be based on such early etymological facts.

Comment: @sumelic, here's some info from Beekes: "ὅρος [m.] ‘border, boundary mark (pole, column, stone), term, limit, mark, appointment, definition’ (Att.). Forms οὖρος (Il.). Myc. wo-wo /worwos/, Corc. ορϝος, Cret., Arg. ὦρος, Heracl. ὄρος. Brixhe REGr. 109 (1996): 640 adds ὅρρος (Heracl. Pont.) < *hόρϝος, also ὄρρος (Chalcid., Megar.), cf. RPh. 71 (1997) 170"

Comment: @sumelic "Etymology
In view of Mycenaean, all Greek forms must go back to ϝόρϝος. This can be connected wih Lat. urvāre (amb-) 'to mark out a boundary with a furrow' (Enn. apud Fest., Dig.); the basic noun is urvum 'curved part of a plough' (Varro) < * u(o)ru-o-, which may in principle continue the same formation as *ϝόρϝος. 
Within Greek, further connection wih ► ἐρύω 'to draw' is probable. See ► οὐροί , ► οὖρον 2 ."

Comment: @sumelic, "ὀργή Origin IE * uerǵ- 'swell of juice, strength, anger'
Etymology: ὀργή has a direct correspondence in Skt. ūrjā́ [f.] 'nourishment, strength', but the latter is an enlargement of older ū́rj- 'id.', and the formal identity of ὀργή and ūrjā́ is secondary. At first sight, the Skt. form seems to require * urHǵ-, but the same problem occurs in Skt. ūrdhvá- beside ὀρθός, and there is yet no definite solution for this. 
Semantically, ū́rj(ā́) fits much better with ὀργάω, which preserved the original concrete meaning." (Beekes)

Comment: Beekes is available online (subscription only) http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/greek